# iOS Simulator 100% Scale isn't 100%

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, scale, simulator, screen-resolution

When I choose 100% scale in iOS Simulator, the resolution of the simulator doesn't match the resolution of the physical device. Here's a screenshot of iPhone 6 Plus being simulated at 100% on my 20 inch ACD (1680x1050), which should have a width of 1080px:

[image: SS]

But it doesn't. Does this happen to anyone else?

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your simulator is displaying at 100%.

iPhone 6 Plus renders at 1242 x 2208 pixels. That seems to match your screenshot.

The problem is that the phone itself displays at 87% to fit its 1080 x 1920 display.

Comment: Thanks, I only found this out after I googled it after reading your answer. I wonder why Apple decided to do this, the downsampling part must eat up processing power.

Comment: Yes, it does. But 1080x1920 displays are easier to get by. Hopefully in the future they will give it a display that can handle native resolution.

Comment: No, the downsampling doesn't eat up that much power.  As for reasons, there are other posts on SO and devforums that go over the math behind the choice.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Hey there, sorry I know it's like (actually almost exactly) 3 years later, but I only just saw your comment got curious about the reasons (especially now that another resolution has been added to the list of sizes to develop for). You wouldn't happen to still have any links to any of those posts, or a general idea of why they went that direction? Is the rendering to 1080 x 1920 done in dedicated hardware, kinda like how the 5K display iMac rendered its oversized display (iirc, that is).